# Reboot on Installation

Tags: windows-vista, installation, installshield

We create an installation package for our product using InstallShield.  We've recently upgraded to IS 2011.  Now, our setup calls for a reboot after installation, but only on Windows Vista.  Windows 7 is fine.

We're fairly certain a reboot is not required.  If we don't the system and our application continue to work as expected.  Can anyone suggest what in particular might cause this prompt, and if there's any way in InstallShield (preferably) or when running the installer, to suppress it?  Thanks.

(Added)The installation mostly is of our own software, into the Program Files folder.
We also install these 11 files into the System folder

```
Capicom.dll
MSFLXGRD.OCX
MSSOAP30.dll
MSSOAPR3.dll
Riched32.dll
Richtx32.ocx
SOAPIS30.dll
Ssubtmr.dll
VB6STKIT.DLL
WHSC30.dll
WISCO30.dll
```

All of these are already present on our test machine.  The full version of .NET 4 is also already installed

Comment: Why did you recently upgrade to 3 year old product?  Take a look at what your install requires to be installed.  Verify the reboot is still required if everything that is required for the program to run is already installed.  Windows Vista for instance has a different version of .NET Framework installed.  There are far to many unanswered questions to explain the reason your installer requires a reboot.

Comment: "what in particular might cause this prompt" is hard to answer if you don't tell us what the installation package installs

Answer (score 0):

It's been many many years since I used InstallShield but you might be able to interrogate the created MSI file with the Microsoft [Orca.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool, this may enable you to determine whether the "needs a reboot" flag is set. You might also be able to reset this flag.